# primeng p-table: cell border visibility on lazy loading in virtualScroll mode

Tags: css, angular, html-table, primeng

The primeng table is showing empty cells when scrolling in lazy loading mode and all cell borders are visible. But when trying this in my app I only see the current loaded cells. Only after the content is loaded the table shows entire cells, see the picture:[image]

How to achieve this?
[image]

I am using the standard p-table from primeng example, nothing special. And src\styles.css look like this:

```html
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="virtualCars" [scrollable]="true" [rows]="20" scrollHeight="450px" [virtualScroll]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadDataOnScroll($event)"
    [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [virtualRowHeight]="28"  [loading]="loading">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
```

...

```
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/components/table/table.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

Comment: you are getting this issue because by default you have set scrollHeight="450px"

Comment: Hm. The original example uses it, too. What kind of value should I use instead?

Comment: Could you remove the virtualRowHeight and let me know what you get?

Comment: @SebaCherian: no changes

Answer (score 0):

You have to define loadingbody template. Something like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pReorderableColumn>
      {{col.header}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{rowData[col.field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="loadingbody" let-columns="columns">
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      <div>loading ...</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```